# React hook form, getting defaultValues

Tags: javascript, forms, web, npm

I have a question about getting unused values ​​in a form

For example I create `useForm` as follows

```
useForm( { defaultValues: { id: "1", firsname: "", lastname: ""})
```

`id` field is not registered or used in `Controller`, how i can get it in `handleSubmit`?

Comment: You can't. ```handleSubmit``` will only be called when you submit the form. If you submit the form while you didn't register ```id```, it won't even know this field exists.

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't seem too logical

Comment: It actually is logical about what I said. ```handleSubmit``` is a higher-order function which is specifically designed for handling the events after the user submits the form.